# Conditional Formatting multiple cells based on multiple dates in a single cell

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-formatting

I'm trying to highlight, via conditional formatting, multiple cells in column G2:Z based on the multiple dates in single cells in column C2:C.

sample sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1yPUUr24hAwFFcfWKdaknEA3vBmIvDNpscobLbMcHHtU/edit?usp=sharing

[image: example]

Comment: How you will detect missing dates as dates are entered as string in one cells.

Comment: @Harun24HR sorry, not quite sure what you're saying here. But =SPLIT(C3,CHAR(10)) will be able to split each date into separate cells.

Comment: Questions should be self contained. While external links are welcome(note: *Google sheets exposes your email address*), consider adding a [table](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/356997/) or screenshots or csv text(like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64186520/)) to show your data structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
=ArrayFormula(OR((SUBSTITUTE(SPLIT($C2, CHAR(10)), ".", "/")*1)=G$1))
```

[image]

Comment: Hi @basic, could you please assist with this new iteration of the above conditional formatting issue? - https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1yPUUr24hAwFFcfWKdaknEA3vBmIvDNpscobLbMcHHtU/edit#gid=1956802292&range=A1

Comment: @qazamy A different and more complex solution will be needed here, so ask a new question.

Comment: Thanks, @basic! Just submitted it - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69768759/