# How to loop Google Sheets paste transpose formula in Google Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

In the attached example file where in sheets “Peter”, “John”, “Albert” I inserted the following formula in B4,C4 (October), B42,C42 (November)

```
=transpose(query({Planning!A3:DT3};"Select "&ArrayFormula(join(", ";text(query(transpose({column(Planning!BM3:DT3);mod(column(Planning!BM3:DT3)-column(Planning!BM3);2)});"Select Col1 where Col2=0");"Col0")))))
```

I should insert formula in 35 sheets for six mounth planning. How to loop this formula in a function?

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1P6Nu90yQQWCdi4Bq14gVXpdZh_TMFsSxxtGjbrmZizU/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: sheet isn't shared for access

Comment: Questions should be self contained. While external links are welcome(note: *Google sheets exposes your email address*), consider adding a [table](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/356997/) or screenshots or csv text(like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64186520/) by *export*ing as csv) to show your data structure.

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1P6Nu90yQQWCdi4Bq14gVXpdZh_TMFsSxxtGjbrmZizU/edit?usp=sharing a new link for MattKing