# Return multiple addresses of a lookup result

Tags: google-sheets, indexing, match, google-sheets-formula

I have a query which checks a column for multiple instances of any cell value and counts them. This indicates how many times social media content has been reposted.

```
=query(query('Editorial 2022'!I:S,"select S, count(S) group by S label S 'Repost Link Column', count(S) 'No. of Reposts'"),"WHERE Col2 > 1 order by Col2 desc")
```

What I'm attempting and failing to do is then to return the cell references for **all** of those instances using CELL, INDEX, MATCH.

```
=IF(A4="",,CELL("address",INDEX('Editorial 2022'!$S$3:$S$100,MATCH(A4,'Editorial 2022'!$S$3:$S$100,0))))
```

I know that these only return the first cell reference that matches the criteria in the formula. Does anyone know how would I go about returning all cell references, ideally displayed in the cell to the right of the previous match?

[Spreadsheet - Reposts Check](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3UJP2.png)
[Spreadsheet - Editorial 2022 Sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jFVBb.png)

Grateful to anyone who can help.

Many thanks,

Mark

Comment: those cell references you want to use in some other formula or only you want to create hyperlinks?

Comment: Questions should be self contained. While external links are welcome(note: *Google sheets [exposes your email address](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394304/)*), consider adding a [table](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/356997/) or screenshots or csv text(like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64186520/) by *export*ing as csv) to show your data structure.

Comment: Thanks @TheMaster I will do this in future.

Comment: @player0 I do not need to use the cell references for anything after this point. This will only be needed by humans to locate the cells where multiples have been found.

Answer (score 0):

`QUERY()` can help you with this. But first you should prepare your data so that when a match is found, `QUERY()` outputs the cell address, not the value itself

Using the following formula, we add a column with cell addresses to the cells themselves `ArrayFormula({ADDRESS(ROW('Editorial 2022'!S:S),COLUMN('Editorial 2022'!S:S),1,true,"Editorial 2022"),'Editorial 2022'!S:S})`

Now use `QUERY()` to find all matches `ArrayFormula(query({ADDRESS(ROW('Editorial 2022'!S:S),COLUMN('Editorial 2022'!S:S),1,true,"Editorial 2022"),'Editorial 2022'!S:S},"select Col1 where Col2 matches '"&A4&"'"))`

So we put everything in one cell with the `JOIN()` function

`=ArrayFormula(JOIN(",",query({ADDRESS(ROW('Editorial 2022'!S:S),COLUMN('Editorial 2022'!S:S),1,true,"Editorial 2022"),'Editorial 2022'!S:S},"select Col1 where Col2 matches '"&A4&"'")))`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=INDEX(IFNA(REGEXREPLACE(SPLIT(VLOOKUP(A4:A, 
 TRIM(SPLIT(FLATTEN(QUERY(QUERY({'Editorial 2022'!S2:S&"♠", 
 TEXT(ROW('Editorial 2022'!S2:S), "♦00000")&"×'Editorial 2022'!S"&ROW('Editorial 2022'!S2:S)}, 
 "select max(Col2) where not Col1 = '♠' group by Col2 pivot Col1"),,9^9)), 
 "♠")), 2, 0), "♦"), "^\d+×", )))
```

[image]

### [demo spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1kNdTfCnbKvFtCIE7YxJk5lKExaFLZamWe-gHWlysgLQ/edit#gid=0)

---

## update:

```
=INDEX(HYPERLINK(IFNA(REGEXREPLACE(SPLIT(VLOOKUP(A4:A, 
 TRIM(SPLIT(FLATTEN(QUERY(QUERY({'Editorial 2022'!S2:S&"♠", 
 TEXT(ROW('Editorial 2022'!S2:S), "♦00000")&"×#gid=950541462&range=S"&ROW('Editorial 2022'!S2:S)}, 
 "select max(Col2) where not Col1 = '♠' group by Col2 pivot Col1"),,9^9)), 
 "♠")), 2, 0), "♦"), "^\d+×", )), IFNA(REGEXREPLACE(SPLIT(VLOOKUP(A4:A, 
 TRIM(SPLIT(FLATTEN(QUERY(QUERY({'Editorial 2022'!S2:S&"♠", 
 TEXT(ROW('Editorial 2022'!S2:S), "♦00000")&"×jump to S"&ROW('Editorial 2022'!S2:S)}, 
 "select max(Col2) where not Col1 = '♠' group by Col2 pivot Col1"),,9^9)), 
 "♠")), 2, 0), "♦"), "^\d+×", ))))
```

[image]

### [demo](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1kNdTfCnbKvFtCIE7YxJk5lKExaFLZamWe-gHWlysgLQ/edit#gid=1562657865)

note: gid can be found in URL address after you enter your tab named `Editorial 2022`

Comment: @markwhiley answer updated